# Clear textbox with a button in a classic ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have this code for the html button and textbox: the textbox is where I input a text so that I could do some changes on the table.

```
  'textbox
   <input name="txtupdate" type="text" id="txtupdate" value="<%=Request.Form("txtupdate")%>" />
  'button
  <td align="center"><button type="button" value="clear" id="clear">Clear</button></td>
```

What I need to do now is click the Clear button and the textbox will be clear. I tried using this code but it doesnt seems to work,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#clear').click( function () {
         $('#<%=Request.Form("txtupdate")%>').val(""); 
   });
 });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you messed the id and value. Your text box id is `txtupdate` but not `<%=Request.Form("txtupdate")%>`. So, the selector is incorrect. You should use `txtupdate` instead.

The correct JavaScript should as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#clear').click( function () {
         $('#txtupdate').val(""); 
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for the reply, I tried to change the code as you suggested but still the clear button is not working. when I clicked the button the text is still there.

Comment: oppss.. forget my previous message sir, its working now. Thanks